# Isomorphism from Natural numbers to the Odd Natural numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove there exists an isomorphism from the semigroup of natural numbers under multiplication to the semigroup of odd natural numbers under multiplication.

An example would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some help.

The natural numbers under multiplication are generated by the set of primes and also have an identity.

How are the odd numbers generated?